# How to calc with values from different rows with variing distance (i.e. can't use shift-operator)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following issue:

I have to calc the percentual change of two values in a hierarchical DataFrame. The problem: I have to lookup the second row by a calculated value based on the first value.

Example:

```
Symbol   Date        Num  Price    EndDate
  A      2018-01-01    1  100.00   201903
                       2  102.00   201907
                       3  104.00   201911
                       4  107.00   202003
         2018-01-02    1  101.00   201903
                       2  103.00   201907
                       3  106.00   201911
                       4  110.00   202003
              :
  B      2018-01-01    1    5.00   201903
                       2    5.50   201909
                       3    4.23   202003
         2018-02-02    1    5.20   201903
                       2    5.30   201909
                       3    5.40   202003
```

Now I have to calc for each (Symbol, Date, Num):

```
Price(this row) / Price(row, where EndDate = this EndDate + 100)
```

So I will get:

```
Symbol  Date         Num  Price    EndDate  NewColumn
   A    2018-01-01    1   100.00   201903   ( 100.00 / 107.00 )
                      2   102.00   201907   NaN
                             :
        2018-01-02    1   101.00   201903   ( 101.00 / 110.00 )
                             :
   B    2018-01-01    1     5.00   201903   ( 5.00 / 4.23 )
                             :
        2018-02-02    1     5.20   201903   ( 5.20 / 5.40)
```

I hope it got a bit clear what I mean. Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue by joining the dataset to itself with precalculated target-dates.